# Nginx config to act as reverse proxy for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create an Nginx reverse proxy server to connect to AWS S3.
The idea behind is that all the requests to my AWS S3 should go via Nginx. Here are the tried configs. With these configs, its showing site is not reachable.

```
server {
    listen 9091;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header Host 'my-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com';
      proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
      proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
      proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_pass http://my-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/;

      set $aws_access_key access-key;
      set $aws_secret_key secret-key;

      proxy_cache_valid  200 302  24h;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you updated CORS on S3?

Comment: Yup, I updated my CORS on S3. Still the same.

Comment: Does nginx resolve the domain name correctly? e.g do you have a resolver defined like `resolver 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: I dont have a resolver yet. What does resolver do?